# What is causing my R script to return longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length?

Tags: r, statistics

Here is my code:

```
Production<-function(alpha1,alpha2,beta1,beta2,D1,D2){

alpha3=1-alpha1-alpha2
beta3=1-beta1-beta2

Observation.1 <- c(p.path1=alpha1, p.path2=alpha1*alpha2, p.path3=alpha2, p.path4=alpha3,p.path5=alpha1, p.path6=alpha1*alpha2)

Revenue.1 <- c(c.path1=D1+D2,c.path2=D2,c.path3=D1,c.path4=D2+D1+D1,c.path5=D1+D2,c.path6=0)

Observation.2 <-c(p.path7=beta2,p.path8=beta1, p.path9=beta1*beta2,p.path10=beta3*beta1,p.path11=beta2,p.path12=beta1)

Revenue.2<- c(c.path7=D1+D1,c.path8=D2,c.path9=D2*2,c.path10=D1+D2,c.path11=D1+D1,c.path12=0)

Production1=sum(Revenue.1*Observation.1)
Production2=sum(Revenue.2*Observation.2)

outcomes<-c(MeanCostProduction1 = Production1, MeanCostProduction2=Production2)

}
results<-Production(alpha1=0.1,alpha2=0.9,beta1=0.33,beta2=0.67,D1=0.4,D2=0.6)
print(results)

#New values from the sample of parameters
alpha1<-rbeta(12,1.5 , 0.5+ 80-42) 
alpha2<-rbeta(12,21.5 , 0.5+ 80-21)  
beta1<-rbeta(12, 33.5 , 0.5+ 92-33) 
beta2<-rbeta(12, 44.5 ,0.5+ 92-44)  
D1<-rlnorm(12,18,0.32)
D2<-rlnorm(12,46,0.6)

results<-Production(alpha1,alpha2,beta1,beta2,D1,D2)
```

I don't understand why I am receiving two warning messages:

```
"Warning messages:
1: In Revenue.1 * Observation.1 :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In Revenue.2 * Observation.2 :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"
```

It is working fine up until:

```
results<-Production(alpha1=0.1,alpha2=0.9,beta1=0.33,beta2=0.67,D1=0.4,D2=0.6)
print(results)
```

However after updating the values of the parameters of my Production function, I get the warning messages.

I noticed that if `c.path12` in Revenue.2 is not zero and its either D1 or D2, the second warning message disappears.

Could somebody please point out what the error is on my code? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're passing `0` as the final argument to `c()` when constructing `Revenue.1`, but you're passing `alpha1*alpha2` as the final argument to `c()` when constructing `Observation.1`. The expression `alpha1*alpha2` is a vectorized multiplication which will result in a product vector equal to the length of the inputs (which have the same size as each other in all your calls of `Production()`). The `0` is not replicated to a length equal to the length of that product vector, thus, when you pass inputs to `Production()` that have a length greater than one, you end up with a length discrepancy between `Revenue.1` and `Observation.1`. This causes the warning message when you try to perform the vectorized multiplication on these two operands in `Production1=sum(Revenue.1*Observation.1)`.

These warnings do not occur on your first call to `Production()` because you're passing one-element vectors as inputs in that case, thus the one-element `0` naturally has the correct size for that call. But in the second call, the input vectors are length 12, thus `Revenue.1` ends up being short (compared to `Observation.1`) by 11 elements.

You can solve this by replicating the zero a sufficient number of times to cover the length of the inputs:

```
Revenue.1 <- c(c.path1=D1+D2,c.path2=D2,c.path3=D1,c.path4=D2+D1+D1,c.path5=D1+D2,c.path6=rep(0,length(alpha1)))
```

Ditto for the construction of `Revenue.2`:

```
Revenue.2 <- c(c.path7=D1+D1,c.path8=D2,c.path9=D2*2,c.path10=D1+D2,c.path11=D1+D1,c.path12=rep(0,length(alpha1)))
```

---

Speaking more generally, this is a warning that R gives you when you try to perform a vectorized operation where the operands are of different lengths, and the shorter operand length does not evenly divide the longer operand length. If the lengths *are* divisible, then R will silently "cycle" the shorter operand to match the length of the longer operand. Here's a demo:

```
1:2*1:2; ## equal lengths
## [1] 1 4
1:2*1:4; ## divisible lengths; short operand is cycled to long operand's length
## [1] 1 4 3 8
1:2*1:3; ## indivisible lengths; warning message, partial cycling
## [1] 1 4 3
## Warning message:
## In 1:2 * 1:3 :
##   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```